# Spring JDBCTemplate update statement

Tags: java, spring, spring-jdbc

There is a datasource configured like below in Spring.

```
<bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource" 
      destroy-method="close">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="${prop_jdbc.driverClassName}"/>
    <property name="url" value="${prop_jdbc.url}"/>
    <property name="username" value="${prop_jdbc.username}"/>
    <property name="password" value="${prop_jdbc.password}"/>
    <property name="initialSize" value="2"/>
    <property name="maxActive" value="5"/>
    <property name="maxIdle" value="2"/>
    <property name="poolPreparedStatements" value="true"/>
    <property name="maxOpenPreparedStatements" value="-1"/>
    <!-- property name="defaultAutoCommit">
       <value>false</value>
    </property-->
</bean>
```

Now, I am doing firstly a DROP TABLE using jdbcTemplate created from above dataSource, then in next statement, I create same TABLE again  and finally try to DROP it immediately in third statement.

```
jdbcTemplate.update( dropSql,new Object[] { });
jdbcTemplate.update( createSql,new Object[] { });
jdbcTemplate.update( dropSql,new Object[] { });
```

### EDIT after @Brian comments

After first statement , Table was dropped immediately, and second statement also creates it immediately but second time, DROP is not happening .. There is no error as well..

Does JdbcTemplate execute DROP immediately or periodically as this is hard to understand , using same data source why should second DROP not happen when first happened 2 lines before.. ?

Comment: Are you sure the created table is the same as the one you delete? What are the statements?

Comment: Yeah, they are same i.e dropSql and createSql are - DROP TABLE A   and CREATE TABLE A , where A is tablename.

Comment: @JB Nizet - I added a 4th statement , again a "dropSQL" statement which is basically copy of statement 3. So, now there are 2 back to back DELETE and the Table then gets deleted second time successfully after last statement.. But, it took 2 statements which is silly..

Comment: Please be clear when you mean DROP or DELETE.  Huge difference.

Comment: corrected the post, it is DROP TABLE  and CREATE table only..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

DDL - like create and drop are not transactional.  Please share the actual ddl being executed.  I would suggest in the absence of having the actual SQL to review that you use the execute method instead of update method on jdbcTemplate.

What are you doing to drop the table between each failed attempt by your code?

Comment: I have tried changing "defaultAutoCommit" to TRUE and this has not solved it.